# javascript onclick button colors and click counts

Tags: javascript, html

So i need to make that the #square would change it's color when the button is clicked and also it would count the clicks under the buttons, but it doesnt change anything when i click the buttons by some reason. the first button must change the square's color to red, second button green, and the last one must change the color to blue

```js
var clicksred = 0;

function red() {
  clicksred += 1;
  document.getElementById("clicksred".innerHTML) = clicksred
  document.getElementById("square").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

var clicksgreen = 0;

function green() {
  clicksred += 1;
  document.getElementById("clicksred".innerHTML) = clicksgreen
  document.getElementById("square").style.backgroundColor = "green";
}

var clicksblue = 0;

function blue() {
  clicksblue += 1;
  document.getElementById("clicksred".innerHTML) = clicksblue
  document.getElementById("square").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

```css
#square {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: solid black 2px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="red()">red</button>
<p> clicks: <a id="clicksred">0</a> </p>
<button onclick="green()">green</button>
<p> clicks: <a id="clicksgreen">0</a></p>
<button onclick="blue()">blue</button>
<p> clicks: <a id="clicksblue">0</a></p>

<div id="square"></div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("clicksred").innerHTML = clicksblue`

Answer (score 1):

`innerHTML` syntax is wrong.

And also there are a couple of changes in the code. For `green`, you are using `red's` variable. I have included all the changes in the below snippet.

```js
var clicksred = 0;

function red() {
  clicksred += 1;
  document.getElementById("clicksred").innerHTML = clicksred
  document.getElementById("square").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
var clicksgreen = 0;

function green() {
  clicksgreen+= 1;
  document.getElementById("clicksgreen").innerHTML = clicksgreen
  document.getElementById("square").style.backgroundColor = "green";


}
var clicksblue = 0;

function blue() {
  clicksblue += 1;
  document.getElementById("clicksblue").innerHTML = clicksblue
  document.getElementById("square").style.backgroundColor = "blue";

}
```

```css
#square {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: solid black 2px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="red()">red</button>
<p> clicks: <a id="clicksred">0</a> </p>
<button onclick="green()">green</button>
<p> clicks: <a id="clicksgreen">0</a></p>
<button onclick="blue()">blue</button>
<p> clicks: <a id="clicksblue">0</a></p>

<div id="square"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the following statement

```
document.getElementById("clicksred".innerHTML)  = clicksred;
```

to

```
document.getElementById("clicksred").text  = clicksred;
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
    var clicksred =0;
        function red(){
            clicksred += 1;
            document.getElementById("clicksred").innerHTML = clicksred
            document.getElementById("square").style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
        var clicksgreen=0;
        function green(){
            clicksgreen += 1;
            document.getElementById("clicksgreen").innerHTML = clicksgreen
            document.getElementById("square").style.backgroundColor = "green";
        
        }
    
         
        var clicksblue=0;
        function blue(){
            clicksblue += 1;
            document.getElementById("clicksblue").innerHTML = clicksblue
            document.getElementById("square").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #square {
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        border: solid black 2px;
    }
    
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<button onclick="red()">red</button>
<p> clicks: <a id="clicksred">0</a> </p>    
<button onclick="green()">green</button>  
<p> clicks: <a id="clicksgreen">0</a></p>    
<button onclick="blue()">blue</button>
<p> clicks: <a id="clicksblue">0</a></p>
    
  
    <div id="square"></div>
</body>
</html>
```